# a question regarding the interchange the order of finite summation with finite integration

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, measure-theory

Question (1) What are the conditions the complex function $f_n(t)$ and real parameter $B>1$ and positive integer $N>1$ need to satisfy such that the interchange of the finite summation with finite integration is possible?

$$\int_1^B\sum_{1}^{N} f_n(t)dt =  \sum_{1}^{N} \int_1^B f_n(t)dt .$$

Question (2) After we take the limits of on both sides of the equation above, do we get the same limits?

$$\lim_{B\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_1^B\sum_{1}^{N} f_n(t)dt =  \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{B\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{1}^{N} \int_1^B f_n(t)dt .$$

Thanks-
Mike

Comment: Why $(t,s)$?  Is one the variable of integration and the other a parameter?  But why mention the parameter?

Comment: @Robert: Thanks a lot for you comment. I deleted the parameter $s$ in the questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) See Fubini's Theorem.  You want $\sum_1^N \int_1^B |f_n|$ to be finite. 
This is just the case where one of the two measures is counting measure.

2) Again, Fubini's theorem, this time with $\sum_{1}^\infty \int_1^\infty |f_n|$.